# Oracle Timestamp error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
select to_timestamp(trunc(state_date) || ' ' || substr(state_time,1,12),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3') 
from state_log
```

above statement giving error

"date format picture ends before converting entire input string" with uk nls parameters.it works in USA nls parameters.

Please advise how can i resolve this issue.

Regards,

chaitu

Comment: Some example rows fro `state_log` would clarify the question

Comment: date format is :11-SEP-09,time format is :11:12:12:320 or 11:12:12:32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you said your state_date is DD-MON-YY then use

```
select to_timestamp(trunc(state_date) || ' ' || substr(state_time,1,12),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3') 
from state_log
```

Comment: ok Thanks,what about state_time.I am getting like 12:55:09:273 ,09:12:12:20.one morething then how it working in USA NLS parameters.

Comment: do you have another example for the time?
i can't match the hours, minutes, seconds in my brain ;)

Comment: 12:55:09:273 ,here 12 is hour,55 is minutes,09 is seconds and 273 is milliseconds

Comment: 09:12:12:20,in this 09 is hour,12 is minutes,12 is seconds and 20 is milliseconds

Comment: it should be HH24:MI:SS:FF 
or if the HH12:MI:SS:FF

Comment: thanks duffy356,but why it is working with usa nys parameters.please tell me the reason.

Comment: -1 Please do not depend on default data formats when converting dates to string or strings to date. NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which is the default format, can be different from one call to another. Please wrap `trunc(state_date)` with `to_char(trunc(state_date), 'DD-MON-YYYY'` so this will work even if (when) the default format is different.

Comment: @Shannon Severance:Thanks for your input,how about time HH:MM:SS:FF

Comment: try it also with to_char(...)

Comment: @user1476092: I'm not sure what you are asking. What are the data types for state_log.start_date and state_log.start_time? Assuming state_log.start_date is an Oracle date, then it holds time information too, which can be included in the string if you want, except that `trunc(anyDate)` truncates the date to the beginning of the day, time of 00:00:00. Also Oracle dates have a max resolution of seconds making the `FF` format code are invalid.

Comment: Hi duffy356,Shannon Severance,Both of your solutions are not working.my nls_parameter for timestamp storing as DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MM:SSxFF,but input data coming as 12:20:30:112.I dont have any clue how to resolve it

Comment: state_time is varchar2 and whereas state_date is date.